# Carthage on macOS 10.15 Catalina

Tags: ios, homebrew, carthage, macos-catalina

Has anyone managed to install Carthage on macOS 10.15 Catalina (Beta)?

I tried to install Carthage using HomeBrew:

```
brew install Carthage
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: You are using macOS 10.15.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's Github.
Discourse, Twitter or IRC. You are responsible for resolving any issues you experience, as you are running this pre-release version.
```

Now, I do understand that there might be some issues, I am using these beta softwares on my secondary MacBook Pro, so no worries but I can't install it and any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Mihai, please, provide terminal output you see *before* the line `Error: You are using macOS 10.15`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The issue is expected
>   'Homebrew install fails under Catalina 10.15 #2807'
>       Mon Jun 10 08:32:38 IDT 2019
>       https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/2807

Suggested solution
To install build carthage from sources in master (commit that worked for me: *e41076782bed7b3609a53f4662480058a65e9a4e*)

Following instructions in https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#installing-carthage to build from master you need to run this:

```
git clone --depth=1 "https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage.git" &&\
cd Carthage &&\ 
make install
```

Answer (score 2):

I run these commands on **macOS 10.15.4 Catalina** and worked for me.

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/*
```

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

```
brew install carthage
```

Comment: Thank you Perfectly worked For me.! macOS 10.15 Catalina

Answer (score 1):

So the issue seems to be Homebrew for some reason.

The solution I found is to use the GUI installer from the releases page. Before you build any frameworks, make sure to switch to the Xcode you're currently using.

If you are using Xcode 11 *(beta)*, run this in terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app
```

and for Xcode 10 (current)*

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Hope this helps!